# Adding an attention block in deep neural network issue for regression problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, multihead-attention

I want to add an `tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention` inside the two layers of neural network. However i am getting `IndexError:`

The detail code are as follow

`x1 = Dense(58, activation='relu')(x1)`

`x1 = Dropout(0.1)(x1)`

`print(x1.shape)`

`attention = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=2, key_dim=58, dropout=0.1,output_shape=x1.shape)(x1,x1)`

`x1 = Dropout(0.2)(attention)`

`x1 = Dense(59, activation='relu')(x1)`

`output = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x1)`

`model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input1, outputs=output)`

in above code i am getting following error

IndexError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'softmax' (type Softmax).

tuple index out of range

Call arguments received by layer 'softmax' (type Softmax):
• inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 2), dtype=float32)
• mask=None
Note that
`x1.shape`= (None, 58)

Comment: It makes no sense to use attention for data that doesn't have time or space dimensions.

Comment: the data is based on time series, however i am taking it as conventional structure like simple prediction. Can you please help me how to solve for above problem >?

Comment: @xdurch0 i have found the solution of problem. And believe me the results are significantly improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved now. MultiHeadAttention layer in TensorFlow expects a 3D input tensor. Therefor to introduce an attention block into normal neural network, there is need to set inputs and outputs of that block accordingly. So the updated code is as follow

```
    x1 = Dense(58, activation='relu')(x1)
    x1 = Dropout(0.1)(x1)
    x1 = tf.expand_dims(x1, axis=1) # here we need to expand dimension
    print(x1.shape)

    attention = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=3, key_dim=x1.shape[2], dropout=0.2)(x1, x1)
    x1 = Dropout(0.2)(attention)
    x1 = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(x1)
    x1 = tf.squeeze(x1, axis=1) # set dimension here again
    x1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(x1)
    output = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x1)
```